# Why doesn't rbind() work inside a for loop?

Tags: r, loops, rbind

I have a range of dates:

```
date_rng <- seq( as.Date("2008-01-01"), as.Date("2008-12-31"), by="+1 day")
```

I have some helper functions that are necessarily relevant to the question and I'll try to leave them out.

I start with the first date and make a call to this function:

```
# Function for getting weather table by airport code and date and return dataframe
get_table <- function(code, date){
  adv <- sprintf(
    "https://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/K%s/2008/%s/%s/DailyHistory.html", 
    code, month(date), day(date)
  )
  h <- adv %>% read_html()
  t <- h%>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="obsTable"]') %>%
  html_table()
  df <- data.frame(t)
  return(df)
}
atl_weather <- get_table("ATL", date_rng[1])
```

Now I iterate over a the rest of the dates creating a new df for each one which I then try to append to the original:

```
# Loop through remaining dates and bind dfs
for(d in as.list(date_rng[2:4])){
  rbind(atl_weather, get_table("ATL", d), d)
}
```

But the binding doesn't happen and I'm left with the original dataframe for the first date in the range, created before the for loop.

This works though:

```
atl_weather <- get_table("ATL", date_rng[1])
new_df <- get_table("ATL", date_rng[2])
new_df <- scraped_data_formatter(new_df, date_rng[2])
rbind(atl_weather, new_df)
```

How can I get rbind() to work in the for loop (so that I iteratively build up the dataframe to include all the data from the full date range)?

Comment: You need to assign the `rbind( )` to the data: `atl_weather <- rbind(atl_weather, get_table( ... ) )`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does work. The problem is you are throwing away the result because you don't assign the output from `rbind()` to anything.

Change

```
rbind(atl_weather, get_table("ATL", d), d)
```

to this

```
atl_weather <- rbind(atl_weather, get_table("ATL", d), d)
```

assuming `atl_weather` is the data frame you want to incrementally add to.

**That said, you *don't* want to do this in R**; each time you add a column/row to an object R needs to do lots of copying of data around. Basically there's a lot of overhead in incrementally growing objects this way and doing this is a sure fire way to bog your code down.

Ideally, you'd allocate enough space first (i.e. enough rows so that you could index the `i`th row in the when you assign: `new_atl_weather[i, ] <- c(....)`.)

Comment: You're right about getting bogged down. I don't know how efficient data scraping can ever be, don't have much experience, but ideally what I'd like to do is write the data to a SQL database with each call to get_table(). That at least would make retrieving the data later more efficient.

Comment: For one airport, in the example Atlanta, it's not too inefficient, but I have lots of airports I need to run this code for.

Comment: Do you know if `merge()` works in place and is more efficient instead of `rbind()`?

Answer (score 1):

I'll risk going off-topic (as the question has been correctly answered already), by giving you my favourite programming pattern to use whenever I'm forced to build up a dataframe within a for-loop:

```
for (d in as.list(date_rng[2:4])){
    if (exists("atl_weather")) {
        atl_weather = rbind(atl_weather, get_table("ATL", d), d)
    } else {
        atl_weather = get_table("ATL", d)
    }
}
```

Of course, if I had the function encompassed in `get_table`, I'd use some kind of `apply` statement instead.  But when real life gets in the way and the inside of the for-loop is too complicated, I would usually have some kind of `temp.data.frame` object which gets assigned to or rbinded to `atl_weather` using a similar pattern to the above:

```
if (exists("atl_weather")) rm(atl_weather) # in case I'm dynamically running code in chunks

for (d in as.list(date_rng[2:4])){
    temp.df = ... # complicated stuff

    if (exists("atl_weather")) {
        atl_weather = rbind(atl_weather, temp.df)
    } else {
        atl_weather = temp.df
    }
}
```

Comment: Tidy means of incorporating the base df into the for loop.